# Що таке «мотивоване слово» простими словами?

Tags: словотворення, семантика

Читаючи цей абзац зустрів поняття *немотивоване слово*.

> Давніми відіменними утвореннями з префіксом **су-** в українській мові є слова *су́кровиця,
> су́ржик, су́пісок, су́глинок, суя́гна* «кітна», діал. *су́голов* «межа між двома полями у вигляді
> незасіяної смуги; польова стежка» та ін. Одні з них називали предмет, що вміщує в собі те,
> що названо немотивованим словом (*су́кровиця, су́пісок, суя́гна*), інші — вказували на
> суміжність з тим, що названо твірним словом (*су́голов*), однак в обох варіантах значення
> дериватів зумовлене первинним значенням префікса **су-** «разом, з». У трохи відокремлену
> групу можна виділити відіменні утворення, в яких префікс **су-** означає подібність: діал.
> *су́пшен* (бот.) «полба», *су́клень* «польовий клен».

Намагався знайти самостійно, але не можу зрозуміти це пояснення:

> Мотивоване значення визначає внутрішню форму слова. У ній відбита певна ознака предмета (у слові касир – каса, Tischler - Tisch), на основі якої сталося найменування відповідного слова. У розглянутих словах внутрішня форма слова прозора (касир – від каса, Tischler – від Tisch). Ураховуючи „механіку” виникнення мотивованого значення слова, можна обґрунтувати природу виникнення назви, тобто як з’являлися і з’являються слова з відповідною семантикою. Більшість учених схиляється до того, що в мотивованому значенні відбиваються не всі ознаки предмета, який мотивує зміст, а лише якісь особливості, що переносяться на весь об’єкт новоствореної назви. З погляду сучасної мови немотивованими є й такі слова, як нога, рука, вода, дім, око, вухо, рот, ніс, кінь, земля, білий, синій, ходити, возити, носити. Історично їх значення були мотивованими. Вони мали внутрішню форму. Але їхня мотивованість втрачена внаслідок дії тих фонетичних, морфологічних і семантичних змін, яким ці слова піддавалися в процесі історичного розвитку і розкрити які можна лише з допомогою етимологічних досліджень, завдяки яким упізнається затемнена або втрачена внутрішня форма слова. Так, українське слово урожай не одразу можна пов’язати з коренем дієслова уродити, тим часом це так: уродити > уроджай > урожай. Історично слово мішок утворилося від кореня міх- („шкура”), бо мішки робилися із шкур тварин. Колись до кореня мех- (міх-) додався суфікс -ок- (мех-ок), а тепер ми сприймаємо це слово з одним коренем: мішок. Внутрішня форма слова затемнена, але вона була: довели етимологічні пошуки.

Поясніть, будь ласка, що таке *мотивоване слово* простими словами з багатьма прикладами.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Зазвичай слова складаються з префіксів, суфіксів та коренів. Корінь - це основа слова, на яку додаються префікси та суфікси, щоб утворити нове слово з іншим значенням. Мотивовані слова - це слова, які можуть бути розібрані на частини, що мають зрозуміле значення, тобто на їх створення впливає певне мотивуюче значення.

Наприклад, слово "книгарня" складається зі слів "книга" і "арня", де "книга" - це мотивуюче слово, а "арня" - суфікс, що позначає місце дії. Таким чином, "книгарня" - це місце, де можна купити книги.

Інший приклад - слово "молочний" складається зі слова "молоко" і суфіксу "ний", що позначає відношення до чогось. Таким чином, "молочний" - це слово, що відноситься до молока, наприклад, "молочний продукт" або "молочний коктейль".

Інші приклади мотивованих слів включають слова, такі як "кінний" (від слова "кінь"), "квітковий" (від слова "квітка"), "сонячний" (від слова "сонце"), "дитячий" (від слова "дитина") та багато інших.